# Get the smallest Group within the same table for a given column

Tags: sql, grouping

I have a table that has 3 columns.
Plate_Id
Prod_Id
Location_ID

The table looks something like this,

[image]

Desired result should be the highlighted rows.

Basically, I need plate_id with locations that are the smallest group.
I don't care about the Prod_Id after.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Explain what to do if two groups have the same size.

Comment: If the two groups have the same size then they return the same number of locations since the smallest now is out of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some DBMS specific you can use `LIMIT` or `TOP` clause

```
select * 
from table t
where Prod_Id = (select top(1)  Prod_Id
                 from table
                 where plateid = t.plateid
                 group by Prod_Id
                 order by count(1) ASC
                );
```

`LIMTI` clause

```
select * 
from table t
where Prod_Id = (select Prod_Id
                  from table
                  where plateid = t.plateid
                  group by Prod_Id
                  order by count(1) ASC
                  LIMIT 1
                 );
```

Comment: I did overlook the possibility where there could be more than 1 prod_ids in my scenario.
Your solution takes care of that for me.
Updating your solution as my expected answer :)
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

One method uses a correlated subquery.  The following uses ANSI SQL syntax:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.prodId = (select t2.prodId
                  from t t2
                  where t2.plateid = t.placteid
                  group by t2.prodId
                  order by count(*) asc
                  fetch first 1 row only
                 );
```

Another way uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, rank(cnt) over (partition by plateid order by cnt) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   count(*) over (partition by plateid, prodid) as cnt
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This version returns all the "smallest" groups.  If you only want one per `plateid`, then use `row_number()` instead of `rank()`.

Comment: I did overlook the possibility where there could be more than 1 prod_ids in my scenario.
Your solution I believe does the same mistake.
Thanks for taking time to address my query though. Appreciate it !

Comment: @AnupAmin . . . This second query exactly addresses that problem.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING : THIS IS NOT A VALID SOLUTION !!!**
Just keeping it here lest someone makes the same mistake.

This solution does not account for more than 2 prod_id scenario.

Thanks guys !
I figured the following out and it works for me.
If you think there might be a loophole that I might be overlooking then please comment.

```html
SELECT DISTINCT pp1.plate_id, pp1.location
FROM MyPlate pp1

inner join MyPlate  pp2 on pp1.plate_id = pp2.plate_id and pp1.location = pp2.location

WHERE pp1.prod_id <> pp2.prod_id

ORDER BY pp1.plate_id
```

But, those are some interesting solutions you had, It'll be handy in the future ! Thanks again !

Comment: That query returns plate-location combos with at least two products. There are better ways to write that and it appears to have nothing to do with the question asked.